# linux - two keyboards one computer different keys sent

Tags: linux, keyboard

I would like one of my keyboards to send normal keys, and the other to run macros when I press a key on that.  Is this possible?

Comment: By "macro", do you mean a bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need two keyboards? If you always have your Num-Lock key either *on* or *off*, you can do what you want with just a single keyboard...  This method may(?) work with two keyboards if you prefer. Using a single keyboard may be faster than having to move you hand(s) from one keyboard to the other.

You can use `xbindkeys` which allows you to launch shell commands with your keyboard or mouse under the X Window System.  The particular feature of `xbindkeys` which can be used here is that it responds to the state of the Num-Lock key.

Lets assume that in your normal typing mode you have Num-Lock ***on***... When you turn Num-Lock ***off***, every key is seen differently by `xbindkeys`. So, you can assign macros to any individual key you like,  eg. I use

- `Numlock /` to put `[2012-04-04]` into the clipboard

To do this, using a single keyboard, I need to press three keys
For two keyboards, it would only need that you press the `Numlock /` key.

- `Numlock`    -- to turn Numlock off
- `Numlock /` -- to run my script (macro)
- `Numlock`    -- to turn Numlock on

Aside from the Numeric-keypad keys, the other keys function normally whether Numlock is on or off. So if you don't typically use the keypad at all, then it may be enough to use `xbindkeys` and assign 16 shortcut keys for Numlock *off*, and another 16 for Numlock *on*. Otherwise you have *all* keys available as new shortcuts..

(for Ubuntu):  `sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config`